# Flower-pot problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The image below illustrates a couple of stacked flower-pots:

[image: abc]

Now, the problem is to with a formula describe how high a stack of pots is in `cm`, knowing how many pots there are in the stack.

To solve it, many people and even the answer in the book from where the picture was taken, would do it like this:

```
Base height of a pot = 16cm - 4cm = 12cm.
Answer: (12 + 4x) cm
```

Now, this is wrong. If I have `0` pots then `12 + 4 * 0 = 12`, a stack of `0` pots is obviously `0cm` high.

How do I solve this?

Comment: That's why we have such thing called a domain

Answer (score 2):

$$h(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0&n=0\\12+4n&n>0\end{array}\right.\\
=(1-\text{sinc } \pi n)(12+4n)$$

Comment: Is this the only way? Isn't there a formula without a domain?

Comment: What is sinc? I tested sin but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Murplyx: There could be, but it would not be as simple as just providing the linear relationship, and imposing a domain.  (Even this function definition has a domain; it is restricted to $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.)  Is there a reason you particularly don't want a domain, other than (possibly) that you find it untidy?

Comment: @Murplyx: Also, Wikipedia is useful for much terminology you find here that you don't recognize: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Comment: +1 for creative use of sinc!

Answer (score 1):

$$h(n)={2(4n^2+4n-3+|6n-3|)\over2n-1}$$

will work for all non-negative integers.

If this looks a little weird, here's where it came from:

> $$h(n)=4n+6+6\cdot{|2n-1|\over2n-1}$$